# Testing that a stubbed method is called with a certain input in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am stubbing out a controller method in RSpec, and the stubbing works fine, but how do I make sure that method is called with a specific input, namely the hash that I passed into the method that calls this stubbed method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expect_to_receive_with_arguments:

```
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(no_args)
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(any_args)
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, any_args) # any args acts like an arg splat and can go anywhere
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, kind_of(Numeric), "b") #2nd argument can be any kind of Numeric
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, boolean(), "b") #2nd argument can be true or false
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, /abc/, "b") #2nd argument can be any String matching the submitted Regexp
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, anything(), "b") #2nd argument can be anything at all
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(1, duck_type(:abs, :div), "b") #2nd argument can be object that responds to #abs and #div
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(hash_including(:a => 5)) # first arg is a hash with a: 5 as one of the key-values
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(array_including(5)) # first arg is an array with 5 as one of the key-values
expect(double).to receive(:msg).with(hash_excluding(:a => 5)) # first arg is a hash without a: 5 as one of the key-values
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#argument-matchers

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Answer (score 2):

the `#with` method is what you're looking for.
following the examples [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#setting-responses):
`expect(double).to receive(:stubbed_method).with(hash_argument)`